# Question about char * [length] assignment

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, printf

How does this code work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
#define NAME_LEN 10

        char name[NAME_LEN+1];                          // line 8
        strcpy(name,"Hi");                              // line 9
        char (* name_ptr)[NAME_LEN +1] = & name;        // line 10

        printf("%s=%s\n%s=%s\n",                        // line 12
                "name",name,                            // line 13
                "name_ptr",name_ptr                     // line 14
        );
}
```

Everything is routine until line 10.  To me, Line 10 mixes together declaring a `char *` and `char [length]`, so I would expect to have an array of 10 `char *` (clearly, the compiler disagrees, because this works).  When I compile this with `-Wall`, I get the following:

```
$ cc -g -Wall a.C
a.C: In function ‘int main()’:
a.C:16:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 5 has type ‘char (*)[11]’ [-Wformat=]
  );
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @paulsm4 for sure compiler does not think that is a function.

Comment: Declaring pointers to arrays seems tricky and uncommon in C.  You can just use a normal `char *` pointer:  `char * name_ptr = name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char (* name_ptr)[NAME_LEN +1]
```

`name_ptr` is a pointer to `char` array of `NAME_LEN +1` elements. So the type of this pointer is not the same as `char *` even if they reference the same object.

The easiest to spot and understand difference is the pointer arithmetic.

Example:

```
int main()
{
#define NAME_LEN 10

    char name[NAME_LEN+1];                          // line 8
    strcpy(name,"Hi");                              // line 9
    char (* name_ptr)[NAME_LEN +1] = & name;        // line 10

    printf("name = %p (name + 1) = %p, difference in chars = %td\n", 
            (void *)name, (void *)(name + 1), (char *)(name + 1) - (char *)name);                        // line 12
    printf("name_ptr = %p (name_ptr + 1) = %p, difference in chars = %td\n", 
            (void *)name_ptr, (void *)(name_ptr + 1), (char *)(name_ptr + 1) - (char *)name_ptr);                        // line 12
}
```

And the result:

```
name = 0x7fff645264b5 (name + 1) = 0x7fff645264b6, difference in chars = 1
name_ptr = 0x7fff645264b5 (name_ptr + 1) = 0x7fff645264c0, difference in chars = 11
```

As you see the pointer to array adds the whole size of the array to the initial address.

So if you want to use this pointer in the `printf` you need to dereference it:

```
        printf("name_ptr = %s\n",name_ptr[0]);                  
        printf("name_ptr = %s\n",*name_ptr);
```

Comment: You should absolutely DISCOURAGE syntax like this: `char (* name_ptr)[NAME_LEN +1] = & name;`.  PREFERRED: `char * name_ptr = &name[0] ;`  (if that's what the OP actually intended).  Clearly differentiate the type declaration (on the left) from the assigned value (on the right).

Comment: @paulsm4 sorry, but you simply do not understand this code. This assignment is 100% correct as it assigns a reference to **array** to the **pointer to array**. And this answer explains it and shows how to use this kind of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In c, the type of a pointer doesn't really change what it points to.

As mentioned by 0___________, the only difference between the `char*` (pointer to chars) expected by `printf`'s `%s` flag and the `char (*)[11]` (pointer to 11-long char arrays) is the pointer arithmetic.

Now what you do in line 10 is make your `char (*)[11]` point to a place in memory where there happens to be a `['h', 'i', '\0']`. Then in your printf call, you tell it to read a string from that location. And there is indeed a string there, null terminated and everything.

So it complains to you about the pointer type but it still does what it's told because it has all it needs at the place the pointer points to.